# Can we use an integrator circuit as a Hilbert transformer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, signal-processing, amplitude-modulation

I want to know about the hardware implementation of Hilbert transform. Can an integrator circuit be used to introduce a -90° phase shift to the input signal?

Comment: For only one frequency, sure.

Comment: For what bandwidth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phase shift? Sure.  That's the easy part.

Or flat amplitude response. Trivial.

How do you do both at the same time?  That's the tricky part.

Typical implementation is a chain of all-pass filters, thus constructing a phase shift with flat amplitude response, within some approximation margin with respect to both (i.e. phase and amplitude will not be perfectly flat, but bouncing between limited extents within the passband).